# How to pass initial properties in hybrid React-native app

Tags: android, react-native

My Android application is a hybrid, several Activities are React Native (RN 0.57.1) , and others are not (using androidX  )

My application class is declared as

```
class MyApplication: extends Application  {
...

}
```

I am following this article to pass initial properties to react-native JS side

https://dev.to/ryohlan/how-to-pass-initial-props-from-android-native-2k2

The article, and every other method I found, suggests to introduce **ReactActivityDelegate**   into your Activity .
And set initial Properties there.

That required the specific activity to be derived from ReactActivity, which is what I did:

```
    public class ReactNative1Activity extends ReactActivity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {

    /* previously inherited from
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity */

    ...
    }
```

However, ReactActivityDelegate wants my whole application be ReactApplication, not just a particular activity.

This is evident from the type casts it is using

```
  /**
   * Get the {@link ReactNativeHost} used by this app. By default, assumes
   * {@link Activity#getApplication()} is an instance of {@link ReactApplication} and calls
   * {@link ReactApplication#getReactNativeHost()}. Override this method if your application class
   * does not implement {@code ReactApplication} or you simply have a different mechanism for
   * storing a {@code ReactNativeHost}, e.g. as a static field somewhere.
   */
  protected ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return ((ReactApplication) getPlainActivity().getApplication()).getReactNativeHost();
  }
```

With these changes to use The delegate, I started getting runtime error

> 3:08:51.706 9817-9817/com.mytestapp.develop E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.mytestapp.develop, PID: 9817
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.mytestapp.develop/com.mytestapp.ReactNative1Activity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mytestapp.MyApplication cannot be
>   cast to com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3581)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3621)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2862)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mytestapp.MyApplication cannot be cast to
>   com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
>           at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.getReactNativeHost(ReactActivityDelegate.java:71)
>           at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onResume(ReactActivityDelegate.java:104)
>           at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onResume(ReactActivity.java:64)
>           at com.mytestapp.ReactNative1Activity.onResume(ReactNative1Activity.java:219)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1355)
>           at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7117)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3556)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3621) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2862) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

I do not think, I want my entire application to inherit from something other than android.app.Application.

Is that possible to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.
No need to use ReactActivityDelegate to create initialProperties into a custom component.

Therefore, no need to make my Activity to inherit from ReactActivity, and, therefore, no need to have my app implement ReactApplication interface.

Instead, every existing andorid application that integrates React, needs to override onCreate of a particular activity and create ReactRootView
(which I was already doing).

As per 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps

ReactRootView.startApplication

takes in, as last argument, what they call initialProperties

which happens to be the *same* thing as the Bundle that would gets returned by a custom (overriden) getLaunchOption of  ReactAcitityDelegate

Therefore passing a Bundle, with your own custom properties into ReactRootView.startReactApplication -- worked.

```
@Override
protected onCreate ( ... )
{
....

        Bundle initialProperties=getMyOwnLaunchOptions(mydata1,,myData2);
        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager,
                 "MyRNAppExample",
                initialProperties);
        setContentView(mReactRootView);


}
```